# Find Similar Strings In Two Python Lists

Tags: python

I have a list of words I'm trying to find in another list. I'm wanting to find the match_words in my main_list and return their values in a new list.

```
match_words = ['reports', 'users']
main_list = ['reports_data', 'users_accounts', 'backups', 'logs']
```

The correct value returned should be

```
returned_list = ['reports_data', 'users_accounts']
```

I've tried using

```
returned_list = filter(lambda x:x in main_list,match_words)
```

I'm assuming they aren't matching because they aren't exact matched keywords?

Comment: perhaps you could use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#module-difflib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what is your similarity measure, but, assuming you only need a matching prefix, you can use the following list comprehension

```
returned_list = [word for pre in match_words for word in main_list if word.startswith(pre)]
```

**Edit:**

If you need to check if a string is a part of another string, you can use `in` operator

```
returned_list = [word for part in match_words for word in main_list if part in word]
```

Comment: Will this work if the match_word is "reports" and the main_list word is "data_reports". I need it to check the entire string in the main list, not just the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

A bit verbose, but it does the job

```
match_words = ['reports', 'users']
main_list = ['reports_data', 'users_accounts', 'backups', 'logs']

returned_list = []

for i in match_words:
    for j in main_list:
        if i in j:
            returned_list.append(j)
```